# Angular component issues

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been stuck for the past few days with this code. I have already tried uninstall and reinstall. The code is correct according to my instructor and works just fine on his computer, so don't understanding why it's a difficult issue with mine.

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

app.component.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 
  `<h1>{{ title }}</h1>
  <products></products>`,
  providers: [ProductService]
  
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'sports';
}
```

product.service.ts:

```js
export class ProductService{
    getProducts() : string[] {
        return ["Los Angeles Kings - Hockey","Anaheim Ducks - Hockey","Los Angeles Dodgers - Baseball","Los Angeles Angels of Anaheim - Baseball","San Diego Padres - Baseball"];
    }
}
```

**products.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'
import { ProductService} from './product.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'products',
    template: `
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let product of products">
                {{product}}
            </li>
        </ul>
})
export class ProductsComponent{
    products;

    constructor(productService: ProductService){
        this.products = productService.getProducts();
    }
}
```

app.module.ts:

[image: app.module.ts]

Comment: Can you show us the module as well?

Comment: Regardless - there is } missing

Comment: @AvivBenShahar i added a screen shot of the app.module.ts

Comment: Can't see it...

but it seems that you got an answer - try it!

Comment: @AvivBenShahar I tried the answer and still no use still get the same error message this is whats in the app.module.ts. import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: `ProductsComponent` does not declared in any module...

Comment: @AvivBenShahar how do i fix it

Comment: On each module, there is an array of `declarations`, add the module components in there (by name, import at the top of the file)

Comment: @AvivBenShahar ok I did that

Comment: This the error message showing up now: 
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:9:3 - error NG8001: 'products' is not a known element:
1. If 'products' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

9   <products></products>`,
    ~~~~~~~~~~




✖ Failed to compile.

Comment: Too messy to see it like that, but it seems to be a definition on the module. I'm not familiar with your project tree - keep in mind that each module need to import external components and services via importing the module, and may declare itself components, as well as provide its own services and injectables

Comment: @AvivBenShahar ok thank you for your guided help  i appreciate you

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `template` instead of `templateUrl` in your [component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component) decorator.

About `template`:

> An inline template for an Angular component. If provided, do not
> supply a template file using templateUrl.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <products></products>
  `,
  providers: [ProductService]
})
...
```

Also check:

- `ProductsComponent` is part of your module (added to the array `declarations` e.g. in `AppModule`)

Comment: I tried the answer and still no use still get the same error message

Comment: @Timmy See my edit.

Comment: thank you for the edits

Comment: @Timmy You are welcome. Just add `ProductsComponent` to the array `declarations` in `AppModule`: `..., declarations: [AppComponent, ProductsComponent], ...`.